# How to find out time complexity is exponential?

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

I run an implemented algorithm. I captured the running time based on each input data. For example in image below first column is the input size and second column is running time based on input size. Is there anyway to find that the time complexity of this algorithm is exponential based on input and running time?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the first, you should rely on analysis of algorithm.

The second - data range is too short to reliably determine curve behavior.

In general case you could calculate logarithm of the second column values. For exponent a plot of `Log(F(x))` versus `x` should be roughly linear, because (formula is edited)

```
Log(A * B^(C * x)) = Log(A) + x * (C / Log(B))
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem you are trying to solve? 
Do you want to see if it's exponential for this particular instance or are you attempting to figure out a generic way of doing this?

If first one,
Use:
http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/activities/SimplePlot/

Put your points in.

```
1,53
2,97
3,155
4,259
5,452
6,920
```

Hit Plot.
From the shape of the graph it looks like it's exponential.

If you are trying to solve this in the generic way, watch:
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/introduction-to-exponential-functions/exponential-growth-and-decay/v/constructing-linear-and-exponential-functions-from-data
If you are guessing that it's exponential you can attempt to see what the params are for a given form of the function. You should also account for errors (ie you may get slightly different functions for different points)